# AutoGluon install failed on Macbook Pro M1

Tags: python-3.x, apple-m1

I am trying to install autogluon via pip (pip install autogluon) and the following error occurs. My Python version is 3.9.7.

How should everybody solve this error? Thank you very much.

[my error, please check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEWCt.png)

```
Collecting jsonschema
  Downloading jsonschema-4.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 72.9/72.9 kB 2.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting grpcio>=1.28.1
  Downloading grpcio-1.46.3.tar.gz (21.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 21.8/21.8 MB 348.0 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/tmp/pip-install-gxevalj2/grpcio_b79061648510414e81b2c5a6c0762166/setup.py", line 257, in <module>
          if check_linker_need_libatomic():
        File "/private/tmp/pip-install-gxevalj2/grpcio_b79061648510414e81b2c5a6c0762166/setup.py", line 213, in check_linker_need_libatomic
          cpp_test = subprocess.Popen(
        File "/Users/liuruiyi/miniforge3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "/Users/liuruiyi/miniforge3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1696, in _execute_child
          and os.path.dirname(executable)
        File "/Users/liuruiyi/miniforge3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py", line 152, in dirname
          p = os.fspath(p)
      TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image of text.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using Stack Overflow. I don't know how to add pictures to the text, so please click the link to see (my error, please check).

Comment: You already *have* an image; I'm asking you to type it in as text.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @ruiyiliu! Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can edit this question, [format your code and terminal snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/1396928) and [remove the image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your meaning. The error has been added to the text, please check.

Comment: @ruiyiliu Can you show the specific command you are running? I assume you are using conda-forge? P.S. it looks like `grpcio` ([github](https://github.com/grpc/grpc)) is the sub-dependency that's failing. Are you on an M1? If so have you seen [awslabs/autogluon#1242](https://github.com/awslabs/autogluon/issues/1242) or  [AutoGluonTabularOnM1Guide](https://github.com/chrisking/AutoGluonTabularOnM1Guide)?

Comment: Thank you very much. According to your suggestion, I have solved my problem. Thanks again.